# Need help identifying this plant in zone 9b

Tags: identification, flowering

Anyone know what this plant is?  I am in usda zone 9b

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You'll find them sold as bacopa, a trailing plant usd in many planters. It's not the real bacopa (*Bacopa* genus plants) but *Chaenostoma cordatum* (synonym *Sutera cordata*).

You can see a photo and read how to care for it (very easy care!) at [Bacopa Plant Info: How To Grow A Bacopa Plant](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/bacopa-plants/growing-bacopa-plants.htm) It's treated like an annual but actually it's a tender perennial. It might even be winter hardy in your zone 9b if it's planted in the ground (but not if it's in a planter).

Comment: Interestingly I don't think I planted it. Just showed up in my pot. Good to know it's not invasive or a weed.

Comment: I think it bears saying again that a weed is just a plant out of place.  Grins.  Common 'weeds' are usually plants that have either adapted so well at propagating themselves, have a wide range of tolerances or they were imported into a perfect habitat with no controls.  Purple Loosestrife is an ornamental that was brought over because it was pretty.  Loved the wetlands and each flower put out a million seeds well, something like that.  Bocapa has become one of the most desired plants for pots this last decade or two.  In zone 9 it could become an invasive weed, must be nice J.!! Love that guy